# CSS display wrapped images in a line

Tags: html, css

I have a few wrapped images in my HTML file:

```
<div id="banners">

    <div id="friend">
        <a target="_blank" href="http://www.google.com">
            <img src="../assets/images/friends/friend_1_256.png" alt="TEST 1" width="200" height="200">
        </a>
    </div>

    <div id="friend">
        <a target="_blank" href="https://www.google.com">
            <img src="../assets/images/friends/friend_2_512x157.png" alt="TEST 2" width="400" height="123">
        </a>
    </div>

</div>
```

I want to display these images in a row. I have tried solutions such as `float: left` or `display: inline-block` but none of them works. Is it possible to display wrapped images inline?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should work. Try something like this.

```css
#friend {
  display: inline-block;
  border: 1px solid red; /*Just to highlight */
  width:200px;  /*Set width according to parent id banners*/
  text-align:center /*center image*/
}
```

```html
<div id="banners">

  <div id="friend">
    <a target="_blank" href="http://www.google.com">
      <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/kMcaV.jpg?s=328&g=1" alt="TEST 1" width="200" height="200">
    </a>
  </div>

  <div id="friend">
    <a target="_blank" href="https://www.google.com">
      <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/kMcaV.jpg?s=328&g=1" alt="TEST 2" width="400" height="123">
    </a>
  </div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this out, it worked for me, hope it will resolve your issue as well

```
#friend{display:table-cell;}
```